# Program not looping properly when cards are a tie in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am creating a Python app that simulates the card game war.  In the game war, both players draw a card.  The winner is the card with the highest value.  If the two cards drawn are a tie, the players must draw another card until they draw cards that do not match before moving on to the next turn.

The app I am writing should prompt the user if they are ready to play a round.  When they enter 'y' for yes, the program will deal two random cards and print the winner.  The result in the shell should appear as follows:

Ready to play a round? y 
Player A: 4 
Player B: Q 
Winner: Player B

I have almost the entire program written, but the part that I am getting stuck at is when the two players cards are a tie.  When the cards are a tie, the program should draw two more cards until the cards do not tie.  The result should appear as follows:

Ready to play a round? y
Player A: 5
Player B: 5
Tie
Player A: A
Player B: 3
Winner: Player A

Currently, when I run my code below, if the cards tie, the program prompts the user to play another round.  This is incorrect, because when the cards tie, two more cards should be dealt during the same round.  Essentially what I think I need is a while loop in the function war, but I cannot figure out how to setup the loop.  The while loop I currently have setup just defaults back to the main function before drawing another card.  Can anybody offer me a suggestion?  All help greatly appreciated.

```
import random
def shuffleDeck():
    suits = {'\u2660','\u2661','\u2662','\u2663'}
    ranks = {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'}

    deck = []

    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            deck.append(rank + ' ' + suit)

    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck

def total(hand):
    values = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '1':10, 'A':14, 'K':13, 'Q':12, 'J':11}
    result = values[hand[0]]
    return result

def dealCard(deck):
    card = deck.pop(0)
    return card

def compareHands(playerOne, playerTwo):
    playerOneTotal, playerTwoTotal = total(playerOne), total(playerTwo)
    if playerOneTotal > playerTwoTotal:
        result = 1
    elif playerOneTotal < playerTwoTotal:
        result = -1
    else:
        result = 0
    return result

def war(playerOneDeck, playerTwoDeck):
    playerOneWins = 0
    playerTwoWins = 0
    ties = 0
    if len(playerOneDeck) > 0:
        playGame = input('Ready to play a round? ')
        if playGame == 'y':
            playerOneCard = dealCard(playerOneDeck)
            playerTwoCard = dealCard(playerTwoDeck)
            print('Player A: ', playerOneCard[0], '\nPlayer B: ', playerTwoCard[0])
            result = compareHands(playerOneCard, playerTwoCard)
            if result == 1:
                playerOneWins += 1
                print('Winner: Player A')
            elif result == -1:
                 playerTwoWins += 1
                 print('Winner: Player B')
            else:
                ties += 1
                print('Tie')
                while result == 0:
                    war(playerOneDeck, playerTwoDeck)


            war(playerOneDeck, playerTwoDeck)
    else:
        print('End of game.  Player A won {} rounds and Player B won {} rounds.'.format(playerOneWins, playerTwoWins))

deck = shuffleDeck()
playerOneDeck = deck[26:]
playerTwoDeck = deck[:26]
war(playerOneDeck, playerTwoDeck)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a while loop that worked.  I am not sure if it is the most concise way to write it, but the while loop inside the function war now works as desired.

```
import random
def shuffleDeck():
    suits = {'\u2660','\u2661','\u2662','\u2663'}
    ranks = {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'}

    deck = []

    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
            deck.append(rank + ' ' + suit)

    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck

def total(hand):
    values = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '1':10, 'A':14, 'K':13, 'Q':12, 'J':11}
    result = values[hand[0]]
    return result

def dealCard(deck):
    card = deck.pop(0)
    return card

def compareHands(playerOne, playerTwo):
    playerOneTotal, playerTwoTotal = total(playerOne), total(playerTwo)
    if playerOneTotal > playerTwoTotal:
        result = 1
    elif playerOneTotal < playerTwoTotal:
        result = -1
    else:
        result = 0
    return result

def war(playerOneDeck, playerTwoDeck):
    playerOneWins = 0
    playerTwoWins = 0
    ties = 0
    if len(playerOneDeck) > 0:
        playGame = input('Ready to play a round? ')
        if playGame == 'y':
            playerOneCard = dealCard(playerOneDeck)
            playerTwoCard = dealCard(playerTwoDeck)
            print('Player A: ', playerOneCard[0], '\nPlayer B: ', playerTwoCard[0])
            if compareHands(playerOneCard, playerTwoCard) == 1:
                playerOneWins += 1
                print('Winner: Player A')
            elif compareHands(playerOneCard, playerTwoCard) == -1:
                playerTwoWins += 1
                print('Winner: Player B')

            while compareHands(playerOneCard, playerTwoCard) == 0:
                ties += 1
                print('Tie')
                playerOneCard = dealCard(playerOneDeck)
                playerTwoCard = dealCard(playerTwoDeck)
                print('Player A: ', playerOneCard[0], '\nPlayer B: ', playerTwoCard[0])
                if compareHands(playerOneCard, playerTwoCard) == 1:
                    playerOneWins += 1
                    print('Winner: Player A')
                elif compareHands(playerOneCard, playerTwoCard) == -1:
                    playerTwoWins += 1
                    print('Winner: Player B')                  

            war(playerOneDeck, playerTwoDeck)

    else:
        print('End of game.  Player A won {} rounds and Player B won {} rounds.'.format(playerOneWins, playerTwoWins))

deck = shuffleDeck()
playerOneDeck = deck[26:]
playerTwoDeck = deck[:26]
war(playerOneDeck, playerTwoDeck)
```